# Is there a maximum character limit to random seed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, seeding

Is there a maximum number of characters (and therfore value) to the seed in Python?

```
import random
random.seed(13) # fine
random.seed(1234567890) # also fine
random.seed(31415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679821480865132823066470938446095505822317253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109756659334461284756482337867831652712019091456485669234603486104543266482133936072602491412737245870066063155881748815209209628292540917153643678925903600113305305488204665213841469519415116094330572703657595919530921861173819326117931051185480744623799627495673518857527248912279381830119491298336733624406566430860213949463952247371907021798609437027705392171762931767523846748184676694051320005681271452635608277857713427577896091736371787214684409012249534301465495853710507922796892589235420199561121290219608640344181598136297747713099605187072113499999983729780499510597317328160963185950244594553469083026425223082533446850352619311881710100031378387528865875332083814206171776691473035982534904287554687311595628638823537875937519577818577805321712268066130019278766111959092164201989)
# also fine
```

I'm not sure why someone would pick such a high value, but I just want to know if has a limit.

Comment: From the documentation:
"If a is not None or an int or a long, then hash(a) is used instead."
https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html
Python does not have a limit on long, only the available address space is a practical limit.

Comment: `random.seed()` is quite permissive it accepts any(?) hashable object, e.g. you can do `random.seed(frozenset())` if you want

Comment: What's more impressive is the Random code *actually uses all those digits*. Just try it by changing the first *or* the last digit, and printing out the first 10 random numbers. (Spoiler: see `random_seed` in `_randommodule.c`)

Comment: I think the accepted answer is wrong about the input getting truncated. See my comment to it, posted below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no max limit, but the input is eventually truncated to 20,000 bits.

Even if you don't understand the algorithm (I don't), you can follow along in the source code.

First, CPython splits the input into 32-bit chunks, and creates a bytearray out of them: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/55edd0c185ad2d895b5d73e47d67049bc156b654/Modules/_randommodule.c#L258-L293

Then, the Mersene Twister PRNG is seeded with the number 19,650,218, after which some mathematical stuff happens that is well above my understanding: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/55edd0c185ad2d895b5d73e47d67049bc156b654/Modules/_randommodule.c#L172-L196

But in the midst of all that action, notice this line: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/55edd0c185ad2d895b5d73e47d67049bc156b654/Modules/_randommodule.c#L180

Anything after the `N`th element is never looped over, and therefore effectively discarded. In this case is N is 624 (it's a magic constant: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/55edd0c185ad2d895b5d73e47d67049bc156b654/Modules/_randommodule.c#L76), so no more than `625 * 32 = 20,000` input bytes are used.

Since the comment in the code says "from the right", we will take them at their word (this is all pretty far above my head, so I'm in no position to question them). Therefore I feel confident enough to conclude that the rightmost 20,000 bits of the input are used, and the rest discarded.

That said, I imagine the definition of "rightmost" is platform-dependent, so it's probably not behavior you should rely on.

Comment: This seems to misinterpret the line `k = (N>key_length ? N : key_length);` as implying that *"Anything after the Nth element is never looped over, and therefore effectively discarded. In this case is N is 624 [...], so no more than `625 * 32 = 20,000` input bytes are used."* But that line assigns to k the **maximum** (not minimum) of N and key_length, where key_length is the number of 32-bit chunks from the input -- and this is limited only by available memory.

Comment: thanks @r.e.s. indeed `random.Random(b'1'*i)` with `i=20000` or `i=20001` do not seed the same random sequence, which I think should be the behavior in case of seed truncation at 20'000 bytes

Answer (score 3):

Since `random.seed` expects `None`, `int`, or `long`, there is technically no defined limit for the seed, since `long` can be very large, depending on the available address space, which serves as a practical limit. There is also no indication of a checked limit in the function anyway.

Answer (score 0):

While if use the numpy provision of random number generation using the np.random.seed(x). The values of seed is limited to 0 and 2**32 - 1.