# What range of values does python's random seed take?

Tags: python, random, random-seed

Python's `int` type allows for very large values, but surely if I pass, for instance, `10**100000` into `random.seed`, it won't actually store that - does it just use a 32-bit integer internally?

Comment: Why don't you try it, show the results? The documentation might give you a hint, it's here https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=seed#random.seed

Comment: @balmy not sure how you could test this, really

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh Doesn't seem too difficult: `import random` `random.seed=10**10000` `print(random.seed)` would that do the trick? Note you'll get an awful lot of zeros

Comment: `random.seed` will always be the method - the only way to look at the 'internal state' of it is with `random.getstate()`

Comment: See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503151/is-there-a-maximum-character-limit-to-random-seed. Apparantly it is 20.000 bits.

Comment: Don't confuse the seed with the state - they're two different things. The seed is used to _create_ the initial state for the generator, in a deterministic way, but it's not _equal_ to the initial state.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a maximum character limit to random seed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503151/is-there-a-maximum-character-limit-to-random-seed)

Answer (score 0):

If you pass as an int, 20.000 bits (from the right) will be used, in agreement with @joostblack, see [Is there a maximum character limit to random seed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503151/is-there-a-maximum-character-limit-to-random-seed). The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=seed#random.seed) states that the int is used *directly*, however, one should take a look at the source to see what it means.

If you want to use all the digits, you can split up the number yourself and provide it as a bytearray, in which case a hash function is applied. [1](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/036bbb1d1b6156a1a72c40e9f907f302505085bc/Lib/random.py#L154-L157)

### Details of the int case

If you pass at as an int, python splits it up into 32-bit chunks [2](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/036bbb1d1b6156a1a72c40e9f907f302505085bc/Modules/_randommodule.c#L311-L328), and set Mersenne Twister's internal state variables based on the list of these integers, by applying a non-linear function on the list [3](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/036bbb1d1b6156a1a72c40e9f907f302505085bc/Modules/_randommodule.c#L207-L232). If you don't have enough values, e.g. if you gave a 64-bit int, another non-linear function will be used to initialize the internal state variables [4](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/036bbb1d1b6156a1a72c40e9f907f302505085bc/Modules/_randommodule.c#L224-L228).